# Any Private Cloud Platform to host hardware in house with Web Interface like Azure/EC2?

Tags: azure, amazon-ec2, cloud, vmware, hyper-v

I wonder if a visualization solution that lets users manage instances in web interface just like Azure/EC2. There should be a list of components as

- Virtualization
- Infrastructure Management (Web Interface)
- User (who uses a private cloud) Management & ACL (Web Interface)
- Instance Manager to create/maintain VM instances (Web Interface)
- Instance Market Place to share VM image by platforms (Web Interface)
- Web API for custom UI or automation

So, I can let users pay real money or virtual point for instances or I can give quota. My hunch is that either Hyper-V or VMWare has similar product, but no luck to find any exact matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only one I've heard about is OpenStack

http://www.openstack.org/

Comment: Thank you, Nick. It seems like what I wanted. Let me look more into it.

Answer (score 3):

Since you asked specifically about Azure, you should also look at the [Azure Pack for Windows Server](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/products/windows-azure-pack) which provides the Azure  management interface (GUI plus REST) plus a subset of Azure features that would be running in your own data center. This includes the management portal itself, Virtual Machines, Web Sites, and Service Bus

Comment: Thanks, David. It seems supporting not only Windows VM but also Linux VM as well. Nice to have and comparable with OpenStack that Nick mentioned. (Linux-base vs Windows-base, Open source vs Closed Source)

Answer (score 2):

You should also Consider [Apache Cloudstack](http://cloudstack.apache.org/)

Comment: Thanks, Barak. This question becomes a list of platforms, which will be benefit for everyone.

Answer (score 1):

[VMware vCloud Automation Center](http://www.vmware.com/products/vcloud-automation-center/)

Comment: Thanks, slayedbylucifer.